# Terminate part of powershell script and continue

Tags: powershell

I made a powershell script, that reads remote PCs registry keys, and prints them out to an html page.

Sometimes remote PCs freeze/hang, etc. This increases the final html page by around 40 sec for each frozen PC.

How can I time just a part of my script, let's say 1-2 commands and if that time gets too large, i terminate that command and continue script with the next PC out of PC name-array?
Or maybe the solution is not in timing, is there other way? Thanks!

Smth like:

`$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users', $remote[$i])` + `timer` runs in parallel + `if condition` for the timer count. And when the counter reaches threshold `terminate OpenRemoteBaseKey & continue`

Comment: In powershell type: `Get-Help about_Jobs`

Answer (score 1):

Execute the statement as a job. Monitor the time outside the job. If the job runs longer than you prefer, kill it.

```
$job = Invoke-Command `
  -Session $s
  -ScriptBlock { $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users', $remote[$i]) } `
  -AsJob `
  -JobName foo

$int = 0

while (($job.State -like "Running") -and ($int -lt 3)) {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  $int++
}

if ($Job.State -like "Running") { $job | Stop-Job }
```

Comment: I think, it's the right track, just the wrong train. A good part of a day i spent making that work. For some reason variables don't get assigned inside of a scriptblock for me, ie `$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` is always empty. I made it work at some point when i run `$Reg = invoke-command -scriptblock {receive-job -job $job}`, but it only works sometimes. Other times job is in a 'completed' state, but no output is there. Any clues?

Comment: You pass variables to a script block executed by Invoke-Command as arguments to the script block. Invoke-Command -Scriptblock { $x = $args[0]; ... } -ArgumentList $foo. Check the help page for more details.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'm just throwing darts as to why it's not working consistently. I'd probably use a few Write-Host calls to trace the state of values in the block. Maybe open that up as a separate question.

Comment: Gonna ask a different question about jobs, i guess. Really got stuck with this. Thanks anyway! After i figure out jobs, i will come back here ;)